# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined in jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider

I have a jquery slider, where I get this exception. The slider is used to set the amplitude to audio tracks. I am new to javascript and jquery, so any help would be much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
var handler2 = _.throttle(function(event, ui) {
    var val = MusicMachine.findOne({});
    MusicMachine.update({ _id: val._id }, {$set: {slide2: ui.value}});
}, 50, { leading: false });

if (!this.$('#slider2').data('uiSlider')) {
    $("#slider2").slider({
        slide: handler2,
        min: 10,
        max: 100
    });
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't try to call `addClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

the problem was with this statement:

```
MusicMachine.insert({slide2: 50});
```

which inserted a new object id instead of simply creating a new field in the MusicMachine collection, which is implemented with the following statement:

```
MusicMachine.update({}, {$set:{slide2:50}});
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the script jquery.js also included in your html file ? It is because you need it to use some of these functions.